# Ampscript Only reading first Integer

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We recently set up an email that needed different content based off if a sales goal was hit.

We had the following ampscript, but for some reason the system would only read the first integer. So if their target was 20, but they sold 4 items, it would read that 4 was higher than 20. Any ideas on why this is the case?

EDIT: The data types of Sales_Target and Total_Sales are both numbers.

```
    %%[ var @SalesTarget, @TotalSales, @text1, @text2
 set @SalesTarget = attributevalue("Sales_Target") 
 set @TotalSales = attributevalue("Total_Sales") 
 set @text1 = "You have not reached your target, but you still have plenty of time to earn."
 set @text2 = "You have reached your sales target." ]%% 
 
 %%[ IF @SalesTarget < @TotalSales THEN]%% 
%%=v(@text2)=%%
 %%[ELSE]%% 
%%=v(@text1)=%%
 %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: What are the data types of `Sales_Target` and `Total_Sales`?  Can you update your question to include samples of both?

Comment: Results of your conditional would vary if you're comparing strings instead of numbers, which is what I suspect is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is being treated as string (instead of number).  You need to use "FormatNumber" function to treat the values as numbers.

IF @SalesTarget < @TotalSales condition can be rewritten as

IF FormatNumber(@SalesTarget,"G") <= FormatNumber(@TotalSales, "G")  ...

Also, note that I have changed the operator from "<" , to "<=", to treat two equal number as "meeting the target" path.

I hope this helps!